# How to unpack libc6 source on Hardy using debian/rules?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

How do I unpack the libc6 source code on Hardy without building everything?

I run

```
apt-get source libc6
```

and I get

```
$ ls -1d glibc-2.7/*
glibc-2.7/debian
glibc-2.7/glibc-2.7.tar.bz2
glibc-2.7/glibc-libidn-2.7.tar.bz2
glibc-2.7/glibc-linuxthreads-20071023.tar.bz2
glibc-2.7/glibc-ports-2.7.tar.bz2
glibc-2.7/stamp-dir
```

What I want is the unpacked and patched source code.

Using google find this [obsolete blog](http://lizardo.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/setting-up-libc6-sources-for-analysis-on-debianubuntu/):

Which says to run:

```
./debian/rules configure_i686
```

But that gives me:

```
$ ./debian/rules configure_i686
make: *** No rule to make target `configure_i686'.  Stop.
```

Besides I want to unpack for amd64 (x86_64) not i686 anyway.

So what is the super-secret target for unpacking libc6 via debian/rules?

I do not want to start the build process. I not have the space for that.

Answer (score 1):

Picking apart makefiles with unusual names using `emacs find-grep` iteratively eventually uncovered:

```
./debian/rules unpack
./debian/rules patch
```

Comment: The [Debian Policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) specifies `patch` as an optional [rule](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules). All the [major advanced deb build suites](http://wiki.debian.org/debian/patches) (the glibc package uses [Quilt](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/quilt/)) provide `patch` and `unpatch` targets.